# req.isAuthenticated() return false if use store for cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have some middleware for session

```
var session = require('express-session');
var config = require('config');

module.exports = session({
    secret: config.secret,
    resave: true, 
    saveUninitialized: true, 
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        httpOnly : true,
        maxAge : 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 //30days
    }
});
```

And also i have check function for authorization users

```
var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('----------------' + req.isAuthenticated()) // true
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
        return next();
    } else {
        res.render('permissionDenied', {title: 'Permission denied'});
    }
};
```

All ok. Now i can login in my site and show additional tabs for authorization user. But when i use store pg for session

```
var pgSession = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);
module.exports = session({
    store: new pgSession({
        conString : config.databaseString
    }),
    secret: 'SECRET',
    resave: true, //don't save session if unmodified
    saveUninitialized: true, // create session until something stored
    expires: date.toUTCString(),
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        httpOnly : true,
        maxAge : 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 //30days
    }
});
```

my `isAuthenticated()` always return `false`!

Tell me please What could it be?

Comment: I think you missed Passport http://passportjs.org/

Comment: when i dont use `store`, i can login to site with passportjs, but if i use this - i cant